# Should a customer/product support forum display the name of the asker?

Tags: forum, customer-support, privacy

Customer support forums are a place where, in addition to having their questions answered, users can act as supplementary product support in order to build a reputation in the community as an expert. Thus, answerers certainly want to have their identities known. But does the asker really need or want to be known? I notice that Quora doesn't emphasize the asker of a question if they even expose that information at all.

Should this information be exposed on a support forum?

Comment: Good question. I'd be curious to know opinions. On StackExchange, it makes sense because users want to build reputation for asking good questions as well as giving good answers/comments... but would users of a product support forum use it with such frequency or in such a manner that they would care to build reputation? My first thought would be, probably not. Though I would certainly add a Screenname as an optional field.

Answer (score 1):

I think Philtune's comment hit it right on the dot. I don't believe most people would want, or care, if their name was displayed. For product support, most of the time it's a "get in get out" type system. However, as pointed out, people do stay and build a reputation on the site. Why not let the user decide instead of you?

- Default: user is anonymous
- If the user chooses: they can have their information displayed.
- User chooses what their user name is

  If they want to build reputation, they should be in control of the name the rep is associated with.